# How to change elements from dictionary using split()?

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

`things = { 0: ["32 64 43 12 67", "14 35 61 46 89"] 1: ["23 54 11 59 90", "56 6 91 11 19"] }`

I want to iterate through the numbers and in order to do that I need to transform them into integers. I tried splitting the strings using

```
for z in range(len(things)):
 for c in things[z]:
    c = c.split(" ")
```

but it doesn't change anything

Comment: what should be your output?

Comment: things = { 0: [[32, 64, 43, 12, 67], [14, 35, 61, 46, 89]], 1: [[23, 54, 11, 59, 90], [56, 6, 91, 11, 19]] }

Comment: replace the second `for` loop with the statement `things[z] = [item.split() for item in things[z]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your input to the required output using nested comprehensions.

```py
output = {k: [[int(x) for x in s.split()] for s in v] for k, v in things.items()}
```